# Serialization with BinaryFormatter *PERFORMANCE* issues

Tags: .net, performance, serialization, binaryformatter

Background:

I'm stuck with LARGE object graph that gets serialized into some 60MBs of file (and will grow over time).  Problem isn't file size but writing and reading times, that go up to 4 minutes on some machines.

Plot:

Since this represents some kind of in-memory database, I can delay-load some of it.

Thrill:

How to measure loading time of specific object chunks?  Do I log constructor invocations and go from there?  Any better idea?

EDIT:

I would rather not talk about alternatives to serializing, there are lots of posts on that subject, I would rather investigate why is it so slow and what part of the object graph is the good candidate for 'excision' and delay load.

Comment: I'm just very interested, what does your object graph represent?  Anything more exciting than a fairly flat list/table of data?

Comment: You're serializing in order to do what exactly? Persist to disk?

Comment: It is in-memory database.  Tables, objects, and so on...

Comment: I had a nasty bug inside my graph....  solved it, data file dropped to 3mb (from 60mb), and everyone's happy now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try [protobuf.NET](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) which has been reported to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I would consider using [SQL Server Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/compact.aspx) (in-proc database from Microsoft) rather then serializing large graph of objects.

I had experience serializing large graph to disk using BinaryFormatter. There were issues related to versioning. Serialized objects are hard to maintain and work with also. And working with such objects generally require to de-serialise into memory. It is resource consuming way to work with large graph.

And Sql Server CE is quite lightweight, its assembly is about 1Mb. It also handles some multi-threading issues.

If you need to serialize just to send over network or whatever, I suppose 60Mb is quite large array, there can be problems transferring it.

**Update**

If you would like to go with BinaryFormatter, I suppose that you can serialize your graph not as one root object but as collection of smaller objects. Perhaps it would be slower to serialize all the objects but it will let you serialize only some part of objects. If you have heterogeneous array (i.e. sequence of objects of different types) I can suppose that the more complex object is and the deeper its hierarchy the more time it takes to serialize it. You can measure serialization time for a collection of objects of the same type. You also can use some profiler to serialize the whole graph, most profilers show you which method takes more time to execute.

Comment: In shortage of other arguments, I'll present this from Server's data-sheet: 2 A SQL Server Client Access License (CAL) is required for any connection to SQL Server, including a connection from SQL Server Compact Edition.
3  A simple redistribution agreement must be signed online.

Comment: I mean, I don't want my users to be more M$ dependent, it's enough that they have Windows :)

Comment: Well, they already have Windows, and .NET, so it doesn't matter that they will have another one small simple embedded database :) BTW if they have `MSN Messenger` they already have `SqlServerCE` (who the hell use MSN Messenger :) ).

Comment: Back to the point. If you don't want MS, you can use something else, like http://www.sqlite.org/, http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/berkeleydb/overview/index.html or http://memcached.org/ (perhaps). I don't like Sqlite, it is quite lame and we had problems dealing with large amount of data using Sqlite, while SqlServerCE successfully handled up to 1Gb database with simultaneously connections (I used it as storage for network Windows Service). There are some how-to's to use SqlServerCe to its maximum.

Comment: Sometimes tools we choose are not appropriate, that's it, and we can't do anything about it. You can't cut a tree with an axe made of paper :)

Comment: @Dmitry: I am here to get some out of the box thinking - you are on right page - but I need to know how to measure the (de)serialization now BEFORE I start to rip it apart like you suggested.